# .net winforms TextBox programmatically press enter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I programmatically create <kbd>Enter</kbd> button press in .NET WinForms? I want on `TextChanged` event initialize <kbd>Enter</kbd> button press without user interrupt.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please define your issue more clearly? What you describe does not make sense as the `TextChanged` event will usually be raised on every character and on the enter key press that you fake. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for **AcceptButton** which would be default button when enter is pressed on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Button` [PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

```
myButton.PerformClick();
```

That will perform a click on myButton. I'd look into why you need to fake a button click, perhaps you could refactor to avoid this?

EDIT:
On second thoughts, perhaps you meant the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  In this case you could use:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Still look into the need for this though, it isn't something you should normally have to do.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this**

button1_Click(null, null)